# Advanced statistics book

Tags: statistics, book-recommendation, stochastic-integrals, hypothesis-testing

I have a good background of statistics but during my researches I realized that I don't have a sound and proper knowledge of some advanced statistics topics such as:

- hypothesis tests like chi-square, f, granger (I stop at normal and  t-student tests)
- special functions like Gamma, Beta and company
- ANOVA
- random variable in the framework of Ito integral

I would like to have a suggestion to buy  one/two good books concerning these topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Statistical Inference* by Casella and Berger might get you started on the first three topics.