# Mathematical Statistics textbooks for self-studying

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, reference-request, book-recommendation

Recommended textbook for my course is Mathematical Statistics and Data Analysis by John A. Rice but I feel like sometimes explaination is missing or things are not clearly explained. So I need a book that clearly explains things with good examples. Thank you so much.

Also this course requires some pre requisites which I skipped but I know the required math.

Comment: There is the classic [The Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman, which you can find free online.

Comment: Undergrad textbooks by Mood-Graybill-Boes, Rohatgi-Saleh, Hogg-Mckean-Craig, Casella-Berger are some of the classics on this topic.

Comment: @J.R.C. thats not an introductory statistics book

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281243/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591466/321264

Answer (score 0):

"An Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications" by Larsen and Marx