# A good textbook for Statistical Theory?

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for a text on Statistical Theory that dives deeper than long derivations of formulas and also considers the intuition and perhaps applications of the topics. I have always found probability and statistics my weakest area in math, as it seems the logic comes out of nowhere. So I'm looking for a text that may ground these concepts more in reality.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281243/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2938596/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591466/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Statistical Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0412041812) by Bernard Lindgren is a good choice. If you are looking for a beginning graduate level textbook then you could review [Statistical Inference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534243126) by Casella and Berger.