# Text book recommendations for statistical estimation theory -specifically MLEs and confidence intervals

Tags: statistics, book-recommendation, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I am looking for a textbook on statistical estimation theory. In particular I am interested in a book that explains MLEs and confidence intervals. Preferably accompanied by exercises.

The book should be readable for an undergraduate maths student.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Try googling 'mathematical statistics book recommendation'.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2281243/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2938596/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591466/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematical Statistics by K. Knight. Uses no more than basic linear Algbera and univariate calculus. Accessible for undergrads, but still contains all the important concepts and results.